How to properly archive YouTube videos on the WayBack Machine
Is there a proper method to archive YouTube videos on the WayBack Machine? I see mentioned in this reddit thread that there are several options, but wanted to know if there is a solid method.

Please review [ask] and improve your question. If there are techniques that aren't working for you include them specifically in the question, what isn't working and what you are expecting from a solution.  This isn't a discussion forum and it isn't clear what isn't working for you and what you mean by a "proper" method.
